# My spl_autoload_register() function is not working for cpanel but working fine in localhost

Tags: php, html, mysql

My `spl_autoload_register()` function is not working for cpanel but working fine in localhost.

Here is the code for input class in `input.php` file:-

```
class Input {
public static function exists($type = 'post') {
    switch($type) {
        case 'post':
            return return $_POST[$item];
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }
}}
```

and through this `init.php` file below I am trying to access my `input.php` file.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
   require_once $class . '.php';
});
```

and now I am trying to get access the `init.php` file in my `form.php` file and I am unable to view the page and it is showing me the blank screen while uploading these files in cpanel but in my local host it is ok.

```
 require_once 'init.php';

 if(Input::exists()) {
   <form action="" method="post">
        <label for='name'>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
   </form>
   }else{
       echo "no form";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The php spl_autoload_register() function usually have conflict on cpanel, Its is best you require all classes manually in the init file.